# How to enable python repl autocomplete and still allow new line tabs

Tags: python, shell, scripting, read-eval-print-loop

I currently have the following in `~/.pythonrc` to enable auto completion in the python repl:

```
# Autocompletion
import rlcompleter, readline
readline.parse_and_bind('tab:complete')
```

However, when I `tab` from the start of a new line (for instance, on the inner part of a for loop), I get a list of suggestions instead of a `tab`.

Ideally, I would want to get suggestions only following a non-whitespace character.

Is this straightforward to implement in a `~/.pythonrc`?

Comment: [This HN comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5660401) has some code to disable autocomplete when the line so far only contains whitespace.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should just use [IPython](http://ipython.org/). It has both tab completion and auto-indenting of for loops or function definitions. For example:

```
# Ipython prompt
In [1]: def stuff(x):
   ...:     |
#           ^ cursor automatically moves to this position
```

To install it, you can use `pip`:

```
pip install ipython
```

If you don't have `pip` installed, you can follow the instructions on [this page](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html). On python >= 3.4, `pip` is installed by default.

If you're on windows, [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython) contains installers for ipython (and many other python libraries that may be difficult to install).

---

However, if for any reason you can't install ipython, Brandon Invergo had [created a python start-up script](http://brandon.invergo.net/news/2014-03-21-Enhancing-the-Python-interpreter-with-a-start-up-script.html) that adds several features to the python interpreter, among which is auto indentation. He has released it under GPL v3 and published the source [here](https://gitorious.org/bi-scripts/python-startup).

I've copied the code that handles the auto-indentation below. I had to add `indent = ''` at line 11 to make it work on my python 3.4 interpreter.

```
import readline

def rl_autoindent():
    """Auto-indent upon typing a new line according to the contents of the
    previous line.  This function will be used as Readline's
    pre-input-hook.

    """
    hist_len = readline.get_current_history_length()
    last_input = readline.get_history_item(hist_len)
    indent = ''
    try:
        last_indent_index = last_input.rindex("    ")
    except:
        last_indent = 0
    else:
        last_indent = int(last_indent_index / 4) + 1
    if len(last_input.strip()) > 1:
        if last_input.count("(") > last_input.count(")"):
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent + 2)])
        elif last_input.count(")") > last_input.count("("):
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent - 1)])
        elif last_input.count("[") > last_input.count("]"):
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent + 2)])
        elif last_input.count("]") > last_input.count("["):
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent - 1)])
        elif last_input.count("{") > last_input.count("}"):
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent + 2)])
        elif last_input.count("}") > last_input.count("{"):
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent - 1)])
        elif last_input[-1] == ":":
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent + 1)])
        else:
            indent = ''.join(["    " for n in range(last_indent)])
    readline.insert_text(indent)

readline.set_pre_input_hook(rl_autoindent)
```

Comment: This is a possibility, and I frequently use it, but it's not always possible to install IPython on every platform/server you're working with. I (and the OP) would like to know if it's possible to tweak the standard Python interpreter prompt to insert a tab when starting on a blank line.

Comment: @MattDMo I've edited my answer to add a way to do this on the standard python interpreter.

Comment: I find I need to install `pyreadline` in addition to `IPython` to get tab completion working now.